# Validar se um dos campos foram preenchidos

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Estou usando o plugin [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Preciso saber se pelo menos um dos campos foi preenchido

Campos> Telefone, Celular

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
 $("#Telefone").rules("add", {
                required: $('#Celular').val() == '',
                messages: {
                    required: "Esse campo é obrigatório."
                }
            });
```

Mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, basta fazer deste modo

```
$("#form").validate({
 rules: {
    Telefone: { require_from_group: [1, ".camposFiltro"] },
    Celular: { require_from_group: [1, ".camposFiltro"] },
});
```

E no HTML

```
<input type="text" id="Telefone" name="Telefone" class="required camposFiltro" />
<input type="text" id="Celular" name="Celular" class="required camposFiltro" />
```

Comment: o que vem a ser ".camposFiltro" ?

Comment: uma classe que voce adicionará nos inputs